# Previous content of std vector is replaced during iteration

Tags: c++, stdvector

I am writing a program which is supposed to find a rooted spanning tree in a graph and all the unique paths joining the root with the other vertices in the spanning tree. I am trying to perform both operations with one function only:

```
void Spanning_tree_finder(){

    int * v=Add_edges(s1); int control=0; int size;

    for(int i=0; i<_g.GetE(); i++){

        if(control==0 && v[i]==1) {

        s1[i]=1; control=1; 
        size=_v.size(); 
            for(int j=0; j<size; j++){

                if(_v[j].Getv2()==_g.GetEdge1(i)){
                Path pnew=_v[j];

                pnew.Setv2(_g.GetEdge2(i));
                pnew.Setp(i); 
                _v.push_back(pnew); 
                };

                if(_v[j].Getv2()==_g.GetEdge2(i)){
                Path pnew=_v[j];
                pnew.Setv2(_g.GetEdge1(i));
                pnew.Setp(i);
                _v.push_back(pnew); 
                };
            };

        Spanning_tree_finder();

        };
    };

    return;
};
```

For the sake of context, the function builds a spanning tree iteratively, which at the end of the process is contained in `s1`, by taking a tree, also contained in `s1`, searching all the adjacent edges using the function `Add_edges` and adding thus to the previous tree one of the adjacent edges. Then the function is called again (note that both `Add_Edges` and `Spanning_tree_finder` are part of a class and `s1` is a private member of such class). During this process, the function also constructs the path joining the root with the loose vertex associated with the newly introduced adjacent edge by searching for a previous path joining the root with the non-loose vertex of the newly introduced edge and adding to this path the newly introduced edge. The paths are all stored in a vector of paths, `_v`. I know this explanation is a bit convoluted but I hope it is clear.

However, there is a problem with this function, since it seems that at every iteration all the paths contained in `_v` are substituted with the path which was obtained in the current iteration. Instead of obtaining `_v.size()` different paths, `_v` contains `_v.size()` copies of the same path, and this holds at every iteration. I don't understand why this would happen, since it seems to me that the function never accesses previously-added elements.
I hope the problem as I explained is clear, and I am happy to provide any further clarification.

EDIT: More specifically, the lines of codes which I think are problematic are

```
for(int j=0; j<size; j++){

            if(_v[j].Getv2()==_g.GetEdge1(i)){
            Path pnew=_v[j];

            pnew.Setv2(_g.GetEdge2(i));
            pnew.Setp(i); 
            _v.push_back(pnew); 
            };

            if(_v[j].Getv2()==_g.GetEdge2(i)){
            Path pnew=_v[j];
            pnew.Setv2(_g.GetEdge1(i));
            pnew.Setp(i);
            _v.push_back(pnew); 
            };
};
```

The core of the problem is how `pnew` is inserted in `_v`. Instead of the element `pnew` being added at the end of the vector, all the elements in `_v` are substituted with `pnew`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], there's too many unknowns in this snippet

Comment: The only place you need a terminating `;` after a closing `}` is after structures, classes, enums and unions.

Comment: And I can't say for certain, but that recursion you have looks dangerous.

Comment: `for(int j=0; j<size; j++){` -- Don't use extraneous variables like `size` to denote the number of entries.  A vector knows its size already by using the `size()` member function.   Using extraneous and unnecessary variables like this will only lead to bugs begin introduced if you don't make sure `size` really is equal to `vector.size()`.  Look here: `_v.push_back(pnew);` -- Now what is `size` equal to after that line.  Oops, you didn't update it.

Comment: I don't think the definition of the variable `size` is the problem, since I introduced it exactly to avoid the program looping indefinitely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure sounds like the objects in `_v` have some data accessed by pointer, and that you are modifying the objects already in `_v` by modifying an object you think is new.

Crystal ball says `Path pnew = _v[j]` copies an existing Path object, which contains some pointers to data.  The pointers will be copied to the new object, but point to the same location, so modifiers like `Setv2` and `Setp` will change the data for all of them.

Try fixing Path by either replacing the explicit pointers with something else, like vectors, or write a proper copy-constructor and assignment operator that deal with those pointer fields correctly (by allocating new memory and copying the contents).

Comment: Thank you! Instead of defining a separate class for Path, I found a way to define the objects inside the same class the function is in, and it now works.